# Orientdb delete empty cluster automatically

Tags: orientdb

Is there any way to delete in Orientdb (distributed) empty cluster automatically to keep a small amount of files and db more clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, there seems to be nothing automatic that responds to your needs. Maybe a way to try to do it, you might write a Java function that checks which clusters are empty, and deletes them. Then this function could be performed or hands every few time or scheduled with some scheduler.